# Is there any technology or method that let user $Z$ knowS which message is $x_B$ and which is $x_C$

Tags: digital-communications

There is a device $Z$ which transmits the signal $x_A$ and receives the informations $x_B $ and $x_C$ simultaneously.

I think when this device receive the signal,it won't know which is $x_B$ and which is $x_C$,because the SINR of receiving $x_B$ and the SINR of receiving $x_C$ is too small,is there any method to avoid this situation?

The only method i know is that transmitting the  $x_B $ and $x_C$ in different frequency band,but is there any method that can solve this problem?Can we design the beamforming of the device ,which transmits signal to device $Z$, to solve this problem?

By the way,device $Z$ uses MIMO,multiple input (antennas),multiple output (antennas)

Comment: You can use successive interference cancellation. Check it out.

Comment: is there any successive interference cancellation about designing beamforming?

Comment: SIC has nothing to do with beamforming. It's a method to decode signals in interference channels. You can use beamforming I guess, but this requires both users which generate the signals to be equipped with multiple antennas.

Comment: @BlackMath If device $C$ and device $B$ want to sent the message $x_C $ and $x_B$ to  device $Z$,is designing the beamforming of  device $C$ and device $B$ helpful for decreasing the SINR  for device $Z$ receiving the $x_C $ and $x_B$?

Comment: Probably you need to design both beamformers jointly such that the signals are orthogonal at $Z$. I haven't worked on beamforming before. You need to do more reading.